# ANCOVA without between subjects factor

Tags: ancova, predictor

I would like to perform an ANCOVA without using a between subjects factor. Is that possible?

I have have three repeated measures variables: truth, non-verifiable lie, verifiable lie. I would like to control for the effect of age (i.e. age is the covariate). I don't have a between subjects factor, however.

When I do this in SPSS, the analysis goes through without problems. I define a three-level within-subjects factor (truth, nv-lie, v-lie) and insert age as a covariate. I leave the between-subjects factor field empty. SPSS returns a statistic in which there clearly is a significant difference between the three conditions (p<.05) that wasn't there before. Also, it returns a significant p-value for the interaction of lie*age.

My question is, are these valid results? And if so, how would I go about reporting them?

Comment: You may build a linear model any way you like, it should make sense. I suspect that your doubts stem from terminologic _ambiguety_ of the word "covariate". In narrow sense, covariate is a continuous independent variable which has its main effect on Y and negligible interaction effect with a categorical predictor (factor) X, and is used in the model (called ANCOVA) only to boost the effect of X. In wide sense, though, covariate is simply any continuous predictor in the model (be there factors or not). SPSS' dialog boxes often uses the word in that latter sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is very enlightening! Another question (more of a confusion of mine): to verify that the covariate indeed has an effect, I must first look at the p-value for between subjects effects. Only when that is significant can I look at the tests for within-subjects effects. Is this correct?